# How can I pass some data from one controller to another peer controller

Tags: angularjs

I have the following two peer controllers. There's no parent to these:

```
<div data-ng-controller="Controller1">

</div>

<div data-ng-controller="Controller2">
   The value of xxx is: {{ xxx }}
</div>

angular.module('test')
   .controller('QuestionsStatusController1',
    ['$rootScope', '$scope'
    function ($rootScope, $scope) {
    // How can I set the value of xxx in the HTML that's part of Controller2    
    }]);

angular.module('test')
   .controller('QuestionsStatusController2',
    ['$rootScope', '$scope',
    function ($rootScope, $scope) {
    }]);
```

In controller 1 I want to update the value of the variable xxx in the HTML that's controlled by Controller2. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Definitely use a service to share data between controllers, here is a working example.
$broadcast is not the way to go, you should avoid using the eventing system when there is a more appropriate way.  Use a 'service', 'value' or 'constant' (for global constants).

http://plnkr.co/edit/ETWU7d0O8Kaz6qpFP5Hp

Here is an example with an input so you can see the data mirror on the page:
http://plnkr.co/edit/DbBp60AgfbmGpgvwtnpU

```
var testModule = angular.module('testmodule', []);

testModule
   .controller('QuestionsStatusController1',
    ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'myservice',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, myservice) {
       $scope.myservice = myservice;   
    }]);

testModule
   .controller('QuestionsStatusController2',
    ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'myservice',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, myservice) {
      $scope.myservice = myservice;
    }]);

testModule
    .service('myservice', function() {
      this.xxx = "yyy";
    });
```

Comment: but is this not making two separate calls to the service? I mean, if the service would be an http request, wouldn't it create two separate http requests for the same data?

Comment: I cannot send "yyy" or hard coded data i need to read from QuestionsStatusController1 and then pass to QuestionsStatusController2.

Comment: How i can send a image from one controller  to another controller ?

Comment: You should use Factory for data sharing, not service.When you’re using a Factory you create an object, add properties to it, then return that same object. But in case of Service it’s instantiated with the ‘new’ keyword ie new Object.

Answer (score 41):

Use a service to achieve this:

```
MyApp.app.service("xxxSvc", function () {

var _xxx = {};

return {
    getXxx: function () {
        return _xxx;
    },
    setXxx: function (value) {
        _xxx = value;
    }
};

});
```

Next, inject this service into both controllers.

In Controller1, you would need to set the shared xxx value with a call to the service: `xxxSvc.setXxx(xxx)`

Finally, in Controller2, add a $watch on this service's getXxx() function like so:

```
  $scope.$watch(function () { return xxxSvc.getXxx(); }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue != null) {
            //update Controller2's xxx value
            $scope.xxx= newValue;
        }
    }, true);
```

Comment: Works in Angular 1.4! +1

Comment: will this work as a factory?

Answer (score 17):

In one controller, you can do:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('eventName', data);
```

and listen to the event in another:

```
$scope.$on('eventName', function (event, data) {...});
```

Comment: This is what I was searching for, thanks

Comment: This solved my question, thanks much!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use

```
 $rootScope.$broadcast()
```

in the controller that must send datas. And in the one that receive those datas, you use

```
 $scope.$on
```

Here is a fiddle that i forked a few time ago (I don't know who did it first anymore

http://jsfiddle.net/patxy/RAVFM/

Comment: You don't 'need' to use `$broadcast`, `$emit`, or `$on` I actually prefer services because these methods create loose spaghetti messages sprinkled everywhere in the code - Basically a service encompasses these into one place with related 'events'.

Comment: this does not work in https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js

Comment: I think this is the video tutorial for the above posted fiddle.
[Communicating between Controllers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OALSkJGsRw)