# Get Data From Two ng-model And Insert Into 3rd ng-model onClick

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

[Database SQL](https://www.dropbox.com/s/na3ymm8mbrnbg9t/sql.png?dl=0)

[App Front End](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7v681psgv2o7xs3/web.png?dl=0)

I had The Value of customer In ng-model="selectedCustomer"

And I had The Value of order In ng-model="selectedOrder"

I want to send these detail in new ng-model="dispatchPlan" on click

i am trying to run this code

```
        $scope.addSelectedOrder = function (selectedCustomer, selectedOrder) {

        angular.foreach(selectedCustomer.OrderDetails.ItemId, function (selectedCustomer, selectedOrder) {

            $scope.DispatchPlan.DispatchPlanDetail.CustomerId = selectedCustomer.CustomerId;
            $scope.DispatchPlan.DispatchPlanDetail.OrderId = selectedOrder.OrderDetails.OrderId;
            $scope.DispatchPlan.DispatchPlanDetail.ItemId = selectedOrder.OrderDetails.ItemId;
            $scope.DispatchPlan.DispatchPlanDetail.ApprovedQuantity = selectedOrder.OrderDetails.AprovedQuantity;
            $scope.DispatchPlan.DispatchPlanDetail.DeliveredQuantity = selectedOrder.OrderDetails.DeliveredQuantities[o.ItemId];
            $scope.DispatchPlan.DispatchPlanDetail.DeliverNow = selectedOrder.OrderDetails.DeliveredQuantity;

        });
    }
```

In The end send this Dispatch Plan In Database Please Check The image attached

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass some data from one controller to another peer controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856153/how-can-i-pass-some-data-from-one-controller-to-another-peer-controller)

Comment: no this one is different
same controller
but different model

Comment: It is even easier then. In both your models, create a variable (if haven't done yet) to store the chosen value from the ```select```s. After that create a third method to access these variables and do wherever you want with them.

Comment: Maybe your models should be on a `DispatchPlan` object: `DispatchPlan.Customer` and `DispatchPlan.Order` ;)

Comment: Please Check The Image Attached
@Richard Cotrina

Comment: @T.J. Crowder
Any Help

Comment: @MajidRiaz, I mean your Angular models in your controllers, then parse it on backend. You'll probably get more help if you specify your input and your desired output ;)

Comment: i had a form which lode data on start of page 
i had Customer Name List in when i select customer from list it show me specific order of that customer on selection of order  it lode detail of the product like (Item.Name, Item.ApprovedQuantity, Item.DeliverdQuantity)
now i want to creat dispatch plan of multipal order of multipal customer
Please chack DB Design and front end design image are atteched

@ Richard Cotrina

Comment: @jfriend00 Any Salution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create New Model In Controller

```
$scope.sendOrderDetail = {
    BusinessUnitId: "",
    OrderType: "",
    OrderId: "",
    DeliveryId: "",
    ItemDeliveryNo: "",
    ItemId: "",
    ApprovedQuantity: "",
    DeliveredQuantity: "",
    NewSupply: "",
    CreatedOn: "",
    CreatedBy: "",
    LastModifiedBy: "",
    LastModifiedDate: ""
}


$scope.sendOrder = {
    Status: "",
    BusinessUnitId: "",
    OrderType: "",
    OrderId: "",
    DeliveryId: "",
    VehicleNo: "",
    DriverName: "",
    DriverMobileNo: "",
    CreatedOn: "",
    CreatedBy: "",
    LastModifiedBy: "",
    LastModifiedDate: "",

    sendOrderDetail: []
}
```

Function To Get Data From Two Different Model And Insert Into Recent Created Model

```
$scope.deliverOrder = function (recOrder, recOrderDetails, status) {

    $scope.sendOrder.Status = status; //Status Used for Warehouse Table

    $scope.sendOrder.BusinessUnitId = recOrder.BusinessUnitId;
    $scope.sendOrder.OrderType = recOrder.OrderType;
    $scope.sendOrder.OrderId = recOrder.OrderId;
    $scope.sendOrder.DeliveryId = "";
    $scope.sendOrder.VehicleNo = $scope.VehicleNo;
    $scope.sendOrder.DriverName = $scope.DriverName;
    $scope.sendOrder.DriverMobileNo = $scope.DriverMobileNo;

    $scope.sendOrder.CreatedOn = Date.now();
    $scope.sendOrder.CreatedBy = 1;
    $scope.sendOrder.LastModifiedBy = 1;
    $scope.sendOrder.LastModifiedDate = Date.now();

    var i = -1;

    angular.forEach(recOrderDetails, function (recOrder) {

        i++;

        $scope.sendOrderDetail.BusinessUnitId = recOrder.BusinessUnitId;
        $scope.sendOrderDetail.OrderType = recOrder.OrderType;
        $scope.sendOrderDetail.OrderId = recOrder.OrderId;
        $scope.sendOrderDetail.DeliveryId = "";
        $scope.sendOrderDetail.ItemDeliveryNo = "";
        $scope.sendOrderDetail.ItemId = recOrderDetails[i].ItemId;
        $scope.sendOrderDetail.ApprovedQuantity = recOrderDetails[i].ApprovedQuantity;
        $scope.sendOrderDetail.DeliveredQuantity = recOrderDetails[i].Quantity;
        $scope.sendOrderDetail.NewSupply = recOrderDetails[i].DeliveredNow;

        $scope.sendOrderDetail.CreatedOn = Date.now();
        $scope.sendOrderDetail.CreatedBy = 1;
        $scope.sendOrderDetail.LastModifiedBy = 1;
        $scope.sendOrderDetail.LastModifiedDate = Date.now();

        $scope.sendOrder.sendOrderDetail.push($scope.sendOrderDetail);

    });

    console.log($scope.sendOrder);

}
```